# $.dialogue() dynamic sizing

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

Is it possible to have [.dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/) expand to fit contents?  I know I can set the width, height properties. I have a table that will have N rows.  I want the dialog to display the entire table.  Only display the scroll bar when the size of the table exceeds the size of the browser window.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Shouldn't be a problem. First calculate the height of the viewport. Then assign the height to the `dialog`-property. Somehow like this:

```
var windowHeight = $(window).height();
$('.myTable').dialog({'height': windowHeight});
// or use the maxHeight-property...
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you not specify "auto" as the value for the height property? From the [docs](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#option-height):

> The height of the dialog, in pixels. Specifying 'auto' is also supported to make the dialog adjust based on its content.

Answer (score 0):

plus for the answer of faileN, if you want to display the entire table due to window size you can set it's height to widow size.

```
var wHeight= $(window).height();
var wWidth = $(window).width();

$('.myTable).dialog({'height': wHeight, 'width':wWidth });
```

Answer (score 0):

Do something like:

```
var $table = $("#tableId"),
    $window = $(window);

$table.dialog({

    // other properties set here ...

    maxHeight: $window.height() - 50,
    maxWidth: $window.width() - 50,
    height: $table.outerHeight(true) + 50,
    width: $table.outerWidth(true) + 50

});

// I always give some room, hence the 50
```

Comment: You can do like Gunny said, and leave the height and width alone, as they are set to `'auto'` and then you can set the maxHeight and maxWidth properties to enforce scrolling if the content exceeds the viewport.  Or if you want to manually do the height and width, you can do that too, like in my answer.